# Zen Coding + jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, templates, jquery-plugins, emmet

I just read this article at Smashing Magazine (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/21/zen-coding-a-new-way-to-write-html-code/) about [Zen Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding). Is there any jQuery plugin for this? It might be good for JSON data inserting/templating.

Comment: What jQuery plugin suppose to do with JSON?

Comment: Not json exactly. Jus for templating - quick data inserting. Zen code has many great aspects, like, you could just make a collection of elements like this: "div.scroller>div.item*20>h2+div.description+p.price". It's so easy.

Comment: I still don't get it. I know how Zen Coding works. You should add example of input and expected output.

Comment: jTemplates can help you with json/xml templating. Not sure how you want Zen to help here.

Answer (score 4):

There is a plugin doing exactly what you describe - using zen-coding as a templating language and json to populate it with data: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-zencoding

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/fluentzen/. It should help you!

Answer (score 0):

I have written [a blog entry](http://www.netsi.dk/wordpress/index.php/2009/12/02/zen-coding-a-very-fast-way-of-generating-html-elements-in-your-editor/) on my blog about [Zen Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_Coding), including how to get Zen Coding options in Visual Studio.